# Remove string strats from a word until char

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have the following string:

```
customer.Id as CustomerID, case when customer.Name...
```

I want to remove the `as CustomerID` from my string, i.e all sentence that starts with as and ends with `,`. How can I do this. I went with Linq but unfortunately take doesn't seems to work:

```
select(c => c.TakeWhile(ch => ch!= 'As').SkipWhile(c=>c != ','))
```

As you see in `TakeWhile` i can use char not word. How can I do this with `SubString` or `Linq` or Regex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
var s = "customer.Id as CustomerID, case when customer.Name...";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+as\s+[^,]+","");
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => customer.Id, case when customer.Name...
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/amrcui)

The regex ([see demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%2Bas%5Cs%2B%5B%5E%2C%5D%2B&i=customer.Id%20as%20CustomerID%2C%20case%20when%20customer.Name...&r=)) is

```
\s+as\s+[^,]+
```

It matches:

- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `as` - a word `as`
- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `[^,]+` - 1+ chars other than `,`

Comment: @JeanA `Regex.Replace`  finds all non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern match in a string and replaces them with an empty string. If you need to only replace one occurrence, you may use an object instance of `Regex` class and pass `1` as an additional argument to only perform a single replacement. As for the regex, [here is another demo](https://regex101.com/r/OuNctu/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Will it parse `customer.Id as [Customer ID]`? Aliases can be in square brackets and contain spaces.

Comment: @JohnyL See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OuNctu/2). You may try it with any other expression. If you have other concerns please let know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have created less complex pattern (see below).

Comment: @JeanL It is not less complex, [yours](https://regex101.com/r/g4CPjX/1) takes 65 steps while [mine](https://regex101.com/r/OuNctu/2) only needs 35 steps to find the match. Using lazy dot with a positive lookahead is a performance killer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Let's take this (legit) SQL query `select customer.Id as [Customer,ID], case when customer.Name...`. Your pattern will return incorrect result as well as mine. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161010/discussion-between-johnyl-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: @JohnyL It goes without saying these regex solutions are by no means *generic* and only meet the requirements set out in the OP. For a generic solution, a dedicated parser is required.

Answer (score 1):

Although this implementation is far from perfect or the most concise it at least serves as an example how this could be done without using Regex but instead some of the standard String APIs with a little Linq thrown in.

```
var queryText = "customer.Id as CustomerID, case when customer.Name...";
var columns = queryText.Split(',');
var columnsWithoutAliases = 
    from c in columns
    let indexOfAs = c.LastIndexOf(" as ")
    select indexOfAs < 0 ? c : c.Substring(0, indexOfAs);
var queryTextWithAliases = string.Join(",", columnsWithoutAliases);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "customer.Id as CustomerID, case when customer.Name...";
string sql2 = Regex.Replace(sql, @"\Was.+?(?=,)", "");
```